# Flutter 2.5.0 splash screens stays for too long with flutter_native_splash

Tags: flutter, splash-screen

I am coming from Android studio (Java background) and new to flutter (still learning).

I have realized that in Android studio without flutter, splash screen used to load much faster. I am using flutter_native_splash plugin with Flutter and initializing it with `flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create`. And in pubspec.yaml, I have:

```
flutter_native_splash:
    color: "#FFFFFF"
    color_dark: "#000000"
    image: assets/images/splash_720.png
    android: true
    ios: true
    android12: true
```

But I couldn't find any info online or any tutorial where I cam make splash screen to last for less time (it lasts for minimum 5 secs and Sometime go 10 secs or beyond).

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, did you try running it in release mode?

Comment: @Simone Pauro, Not yet. Would that make any difference in Release mode? didn't know that.

Comment: Yes, performances while running in debug mode shouldn't be taken into consideration

Comment: I see. In that case I will ignore it for the moment.. Thanks for your help.